# Array is not an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongoose, ecmascript-6

I have a object that looks like an array

```
var questions = 

[ { started_time: 2017-05-04T12:46:39.439Z,
    word: 'bottle',
    questionId: '161013bd-00cc-4ad1-8f98-1a8384e202c8' },
  { started_time: 2017-05-04T12:47:26.130Z,
    word: 'play',
    questionId: 'a84bd1b4-8b9c-4ec7-862d-ba994ac1f371' },
  { started_time: 2017-05-04T12:47:50.156Z,
    word: 'bottle',
    questionId: '4c7e1ee8-651e-4086-8e69-ce64414a815a' },
  { started_time: 2017-05-04T12:54:40.703Z,
    word: 'was',
    questionId: '79412420-eee9-47e0-8fb8-d854c5889765' },
  { started_time: 2017-05-04T12:55:36.474Z,
    word: 'liked',
    questionId: '525d90c9-4cca-433c-99c5-56bb54756b9c' } ]
```

I'm trying to create an array of words like this:

```
["bottle", "play", "was", "liked"]
```

When I try questions.map(etc..) I get

```
TypeError: questions.map is not a function
```

and Array.isArray(questions) is false

I can not figure out why I can't treat this as an array. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Assuming the `started_time` values are delimited in some way in your real code rather than being unenclosed as above, that doesn't just *look* like an array, it is an array: https://jsfiddle.net/9Lgt5abm/ If they aren't, well, that's likely to be a bit of a problem, as they're a syntax error, but it's hard to see how you'd get *that* error message in that case.

Comment: When I take your code as is and paste it into the Chrome dev tools, I get an error because each `started_time` is invalid.  Those need to be strings or Date objects.

Comment: Executing that asignation throws a syntax error, started_time should be a string and therefore each value should go between quotes

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
var question = [ 
            { 
            started_time: '2017-05-04T12:46:39.439Z',
            word: 'bottle',
            questionId: '161013bd-00cc-4ad1-8f98-1a8384e202c8' 
            },
            {
            started_time: `2017-05-04T12:47:26.130Z`,
            word: 'play',
            questionId: 'a84bd1b4-8b9c-4ec7-862d-ba994ac1f371'
            }
          ];


//console.log(JSON.stringify(question) + "<br>");

var result = question.map(function(x){
  return x.word;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Downvoter, please leave a comment for me. I have given the solution which is simple to understand.

Comment: Let me know if my solution solved your problem for your new array.

Comment: Still having this problem, I removed the dates. Mongoose is returning an object that looks like an array but isn't:
var query = Challenges.findOne({"_id":newQuestion.challengeId}).select('question.word')
    
    query.exec(function (err, questions){`

    var questionsNoDate = questions.question`

    console.log(typeof(questionsNoDate))`
    console.log(Array.isArray(questionsNoDate))`
    console.log(questionsNoDate)`
</code>

Returns:

object
false
[ { word: 'honest' },
  { word: 'bottle' },
  { word: 'bottle' } ]

How do I convert this to a normal array?

Comment: Fixed it!!! Needed to add .lean() to my Mongoose query